# Is exposing moment.js to $rootScope good practice?

Tags: angularjs, momentjs

I started working with an AngularJs app. In `index.js`, A series of moment.js functions are exported to `$rootScope`. 
The author did this to make these functions accessible from the HTML files. For example,

```
RSApp.run(function ($rootScope) {
    $rootScope.toTime = function (date)     {　return moment(date).format('HH:mm:ss');　};
    $rootScope.toCalendar = function (date) {　return moment(date).calendar();　};
    $rootScope.fromNow = function (date)    {　return moment(date).fromNow();　};
    ...
```

Instead of polluting `$rootScope` like this, I'm thinking of simply exposing `moment` itself, and call specific moment.js functions in HTML.

```
RSApp.run(function ($rootScope) {
    $rootScope.moment = moment;
```

My question is, is exposing `moment` to `$rootScope` like this considered good practice?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No, it's not. Actually it's a very bad practice. The better way to expose functionality is through `services` and `factories`.

The problem is that scopes are part of the dirty checking for two way data binding, if you add more stuff that doesn't belong to scope, would be only extra garbage for angularjs to check during the digestion cycle.

You can use something like this:

```
angular.module('myMod')
  .factory('dateUtil', function() {
    return {
      toTime: function(date) {　
        return moment(date).format('HH:mm:ss');　
      },
      toCalendar: function(date) {　
        return moment(date).calendar();　
      },
      fromNow: function(date) {　
        return
        moment(date).fromNow();　
      }
    };
  });
```

Also, if you are trying to use those helper in the view, you wanted to expose it on the `$rootScope` at first place, you should use angulajs filters, so you'd be able to do something like `{{ new Date() | toTime }}` on your views.

For example:

```
angular.module('myMod')
  .filter('toTime', function() {
    return function(date) {　
      return moment(date).format('HH:mm:ss');　
    };
  });
```

> **Note:** Consider checking out [`angular-moment`](https://github.com/urish/angular-moment) it might be usefull, it has services and filter to be used already in the angularjs way.

Answer (score 2):

Moment can be made injectable by creating a [module.constant service](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/auto/service/$provide#constant):

```
RSApp.constant("moment", moment);
```

Then inject it wherever needed:

```
RSApp.controller("myCtrl", function($scope, moment) {
    //code here
});
```

> ## `$rootScope` exists, but it can be used for evil
>
> Scopes in AngularJS form a hierarchy, prototypically inheriting from a root scope at the top of the tree. Usually this can be ignored, since most views have a controller, and therefore a scope, of their own.
>
> Occasionally there are pieces of data that you want to make global to the whole app. For these, you can inject `$rootScope` and set values on it like any other scope. Since the scopes inherit from the root scope, these values will be available to the expressions attached to directives like `ng-show` just like values on your local `$scope`.
>
> Of course, global state sucks and you should use `$rootScope` sparingly, like you would (hopefully) use with global variables in any language. In particular, don't use it for code, only data. If you're tempted to put a function on `$rootScope`, it's almost always better to put it in a service that can be injected where it's needed, and more easily tested.
>
> Conversely, don't create a service whose only purpose in life is to store and return bits of data.
>
> [— AngularJS FAQ - `$rootScope` exists, but it can be used for evil](https://docs.angularjs.org/misc/faq#-rootscope-exists-but-it-can-be-used-for-evil)